# Add column with sample size for each model to results dataframe

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, data-manipulation

I am running regression models in the `mtcars` dataset and exporting results to a dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

outcomes <- c("wt", "mpg", "hp", "disp")
exposures <- c("gear", "vs", "am")
covariates <- c("drat", "qsec")

expand.grid(outcomes, exposures, covariates) %>%
group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
summarise(Var3 = paste0(Var3, collapse = "+")) %>%
rowwise() %>%
summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~factor(", Var2, ")+", Var3)) %>%
group_by(model_id = row_number(),
       frm, samplesize=nrow(mtcars)) %>%
do(tidy(lm(.$frm, data = mtcars))) %>%
ungroup()
```

I know `mtcars` has no missing data, but if my dataframe contained missing values, then will the column `samplesize` show the sample size for each model i.e. for each combination of `frm`?

Comment: What *is* the sample size for each model? `nrow(mtcars)`?

Comment: How would you modify the code to add that information as a column to the results?

Comment: Change `summarise(...)` to `summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~factor(", Var2, ")+", Var3), samplesize=nrow(mtcars))`?

Comment: In what @CPak said, you would then need to include `samplesize` in your `group_by`, or it will get lost in the `do` call. But unless I'm missing something, won't every model have the same sample size? Or is there a situation where this will be used on different subsets of data?

Comment: Thanks @camille I am using this code my own data which has missing values (mtcars probably wasn't the best to use for example). That seems to work - i wonder though will it give the different sample sizes for each model if these  had different Ns (or is it just reporting the sample size for the whole dataset.

Comment: Yes, using `samplesize = nrow(mtcars)` would just give the same value each time, since `mtcars` itself isn't changing. I can't quite wrap my head around this, but it's an interesting question. I think you might have some luck with the `invoke` functions and the [Many Models](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) chapter of R for Data Science